# Telerik Grid null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I am trying to use the repaint method of Telerik Grid while resizing. In the code below the variable grid is always null and hence I can't call the repaint method.

Am I calling the grid before it is loaded on the page? Can anybody suggest how to get this working?

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock runat="server" ID="MainScriptBlock">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.$ = $telerik.$;

            jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resize);
            jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resize);

            function resize() {                  
                 var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
                var h = $(window).height();             
                $(".resizeGrid").css({ 'height': (h - 60) });
                grid.repaint();
            }                       
        </script>
    </telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the repaintGrid function.  I found this in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-repaint.html).

```
function repaintGrid(sender, args) {
    var grid = $find("<%=RadGrid1.ClientID %>");
    grid.repaint();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think grid.repaint(); does the same thing. And if I have to call the repaintGrid() method - how do I call it from within my resize function?

Answer (score 0):

In Telerik MVC Extensions i use:

```
$(".t-grid-content:first", Grid).css("height", NewHeight + "px");
```

Hope it helps